# In App StatusBar Color ... Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, statusbar

I am currently using a note 7 mm app on stock note 4 mm.
its working perfectly but there is only one problem, the status bar is full white color on a white bg [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWXug.png)

i am trying but the problem is the app is note decompiling without any errors and even if i do manage to do that it just doesn't recompile. i am using apktool

can anyone guide me on how to do this ?? please
is there any way to do it without decompiling ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to change the color from statusBar when is White.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (getWindow().getStatusBarColor() == Color.WHITE)
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lollipop_status_bar_color));
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
I managed to do it by editing xml and fixing errors ...